# Jquery sortable function not working in Android?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, jquery-ui, android-ndk

I want to use sortable function in my android application ([Showed in this link-jquery UI)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

It is working well in the normal browser while the same application failed to make this sortable function property in android phones.How to overcome from this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah i found out the answer from this [link](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch)

We have to include this js in our html page,it will support sortable function in android.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Ui library is designed to work with mouse events. Sortable component works on "mousemove" event.

Mobile browsers simulates "click" events over "touchstart,touchend", but does not simulate "mousemove" events.

You need to replace the logic related to mousedown,mousemove,mouseup with touch events. These are touchstart, touchmove, touchend.

Have a look at the code in here
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js